# Is LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE sufficient for an UPSERT in JPA?

Tags: jpa, concurrency, upsert, pessimistic-locking

I've read [this article on JPA concurrency](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/locking_and_concurrency_in_java), but either I am too thick or it is not explicit enough.

I am looking to do a database-controlled atomic update-if-found-else-insert operation (an `UPSERT`).

It *looks* to my poor slow brain that I can--within a transaction of course--run a named query with a lock mode of `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`, see if it returns any results, and then either a `persist()` or an `update()` afterwards.

What I am not clear on are the differences between doing this operation with a `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` lock vs. a `PESSIMISTIC_READ` lock.  I've read the sentences--I understand that `PESSIMISTIC_READ` is intended to prevent non-repeatable reads, and `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` is...well, maybe I don't understand that one so well :-) --but underneath it's just a SQL `SELECT FOR UPDATE`, yeah?  In both cases?

Comment: Hi Laird. Did you had any opportunity to work on this? Any interesting finding?

Comment: I haven't had the time to dig in and see what's actually going on.  I put in a PESSIMISTIC_WRITE lock because the concurrency article seemed to be trying to insinuate that this would in fact allow me to do a race-condition-less UPSERT.  Tangent: an UPSERT seems like such an unbelievably common operation that there MUST be a way to do it in JPA.

Comment: I have the feeling I miss something here. Why can't you just do a find() + insert() if necessary. I suppose the transaction will guarantee the atomicity? I think the locking type is less important, you could even use optimistic locking + versioning? I suppose duplicate entries are protected using a unique constraint.

Answer (score 4):

> I am looking to do a database-controlled atomic update-if-found-else-insert operation (an UPSERT).

I'm maybe not answering exactly the whole question but if you want to implement the above without any race condition, you need IMO a **table-level** LOCK IN EXCLUSIVE MODE (not only rows). I don't know if this can be done with JPA. Maybe you could clarify what would be acceptable for you.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this kind of situation and found this:

> Pessimistic Locking, that means locking of objects on transaction begin and keeping the lock during transaction is done by these 2 PessimisticLockModes:
>   - LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ -->
>   entity can be read by other transactions but no changes can be made 
>   - LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE -->
>   entity can not be read or written by other transactions

[link](http://javaenterpriseworld.blogspot.com/2012/03/optimistic-pessimistic-locking.html) to the article

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking to do a database-controlled atomic
>   update-if-found-else-insert operation (an UPSERT).

[*`INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) does that.